# Auto login not working on SO

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

It works fine on every other site, just on SO it recently stopped working.

I just get the page and the regular orange bar when I'm expecting the white overlay bar to tell me I'm logged in and to refresh the page. Like I said, it works normally on every site except SO.

The error console reports an error when I load the page:

> $("#topbar a[href^='/users/recent/']:first").attr("href") is undefined

Included is a picture of it not working, along with the error console.

[image: Error console]

**Edit:** after closing out of and reopening Firefox, the problem went away. Any reason why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an error in a Greasemonkey script, not something in Stack Overflow.

Global Login is really JavaScript heavy, so any errors could gum the whole thing up.

Comment: Oh, whoops. You're absolutely right. I had an old GreaseMonkey script that I didn't even remember installing! I uninstalled it once I noticed it.